# Sub-Queries in Netezza

Tags: oracle, netezza

I am trying to port a SQL from Oracle 11 G to Netezza.

Here is my query in Oracle:

```
SELECT
    ID, TEACHERID, CLASS, SECTION, MAJOR, SUPERVISOR, COURSE, SCORE, SCOREDATE, 
    (select SCORE from STUDENT_SCORES d2 where d2.ID=d1.ID and d2.SCOREDATE (d1.SCOREDATE)-28 and d1.COURSE=d2.COURSE)  as PRIORSCORE, 
    (d1.SCOREDATE)-28 as PRIORSCOREDT,
    REMCD
FROM 
    STUDENT_SCORES d1
WHERE 
    TEACHERID='T1' AND SCOREDATE=(SELECT MAX(SCOREDATE) FROM STUDENT_SCORES WHERE TEACHERID='T1')
```

When I run this in Netezza I get an error:

```
ERROR:  (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting
```

How do I rewrite this query for Netezza? Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that the subquery in your `select` clause (`PRIORSCORE`) does not return multiple rows?

Comment: Please find your answer [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.dbu.doc%2Fc_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html) . You cannot use correlated subqueries in `SELECT` lists.

Comment: Maheswaran Ravishankar Yes I understand I cannot use correlated subqueries but how do I rewrite this for Netezza?

Comment: Did you get your question answered here, or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rewriting your code to this:

```
select d1.ID, d1.TEACHERID, d1.CLASS, d1.SECTION, d1.MAJOR, d1.SUPERVISOR, d1.COURSE, d1.SCORE, d1.SCOREDATE
,d2.SCORE as PRIORSCORE
,d2.SCOREDATE as PRIORSCOREDT
,d1.REMCD
from STUDENT_SCORES d1 left outer join
(select * from STUDENT_SCORES ss where ss.SCOREDATE = (SELECT MAX(SCOREDATE)-28 FROM STUDENT_SCORES WHERE TEACHERID='T1') d2
on  d1.ID=d2.ID
and d1.COURSE=d2.COURSE
where d1.TEACHERID='T1'
and d1.SCOREDATE = (SELECT MAX(SCOREDATE) FROM STUDENT_SCORES WHERE TEACHERID='T1')
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Netezza [Docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html)

- You cannot use correlated subqueries in SET operations (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, and `MINUS`).
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in aggregates with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in ORed clauses or in `CASE`/`WHEN` expressions.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in `IN` lists.
- You cannot use correlated subqueries in `SELECT` lists.

**Rewritten Query: (Oracle)** (Not Sure with *Netezza* Syntax)

```
SELECT
    d1.ID, d1.TEACHERID, d1.CLASS, d1.SECTION, d1.MAJOR, d1.SUPERVISOR, d1.COURSE, d1.SCORE, d1.SCOREDATE, 
    d2.SCORE as PRIORSCORE, 
    (d1.SCOREDATE)-28 as PRIORSCOREDT,
    d1.REMCD
FROM 
    STUDENT_SCORES d1
LEFT JOIN STUDENT_SCORES d2
ON (d2.ID=d1.ID and d2.SCOREDATE = (d1.SCOREDATE)-28 and d1.COURSE=d2.COURSE)
WHERE 
    d1.TEACHERID='T1' AND d1.SCOREDATE=(SELECT MAX(d3.SCOREDATE) FROM STUDENT_SCORES d3 WHERE d3.TEACHERID='T1')
```